# Frontend oder Front-End

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context, hyphen

Ich finde mehrere Bedeutungen und mehrere Schreibweisen für das Front(-)End. Würde ich das Wort im Duden finden, bräuchte ich natürlich nicht zu fragen, aber in diesem Fall, wo wir wieder in der IT sind, ist es einfach ein Begriff, der im englischsprachigen Raum seinen Ursprung hat und die "korrekte" Schreibweise in Deutschen nicht definiert zu sein scheint, oder doch?

Ich finde jedenfalls Quellen mit beiden Schreibweisen. Intuitiv hätte ich 'Frontend ' geschrieben, aber bei Wikipedia zum Beispiel wird das 'Front-End' für IT mit Bindestrich geschrieben und das für Autos ohne.

Die Meinungen gehen auseinander. Hat vielleicht jemand eine zuverlässige Quelle, die ich jetzt nicht gefunden habe, die diese Frage klärt?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Frontend

Answer (score 8):

Es gibt auch im Englischen zwei Varianten, siehe [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/front-end), nämlich *getrennt* (was für das Deutsche nicht in Frage kommt) und *mit Bindestrich*. Denn: Ich halte es für nahe liegend, beim Import eines Wortes aus einer Fremdsprache eine Variante zu wählen, die auch in der Fremdsprache korrekt ist. Hier ist die Schreibung mit Bindestrich eine Schnittmenge.

Die Schreibung mit Bindestrich betrachte ich im Deutschen als Hilfe für den Leser über die Zusammensetzung und das trifft noch verstärkt auf das *Back-End* zu, das zusammen geschrieben auch noch das Partizip Präsens zu *backen* sein könnte.

Prinzipiell lassen die Rechtschreibregeln §37/E4 für diesen Fall (Adjektiv + Substantiv aus dem Englischen, erste Komponente betont) neben dem Bindestrich auch die Zusammenschreibung zu.

Comment: Welche Rolle spielt es, wie viele Schreibungen die englische Sprache erlaubt? Inhaltlich ist eine Kollision mit backend weitgehend ausgeschlossen, dazu kommt die Stellung im Satz sowie die Groß-/Kleinschreibung.

Comment: Zu deinem letzten Absatz: Die Regeln widersprechen dem Teil in Klammern im ersten.

Answer (score 7):

Im Deutschen gibt es relativ wenige Wörter mit Bindestrich. Deutsch ist bekannt für seine Flexibilität der so genannten [Komposition](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)), die in der Regel ohne Bindestrich durchgeführt wird.

Bindestriche werden kurz zusammengefasst bei Abkürzungen, Zahlkombinationen, besonderen Hervorhebungen, Namen und eben auch Anglizismen verwendet.

Eine schöne und ausführlich Ausführung, wann ein Bindestrich benutzt wird, ist hier zu finden: http://www.textpertise.de/sprachtipp-05-2003.html

Obige Seite, der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Fremdwortern-aus-dem-Englischen) und auch ich empfehlen Anglizsmen nach Möglichkeit eher ohne Bindestrich zu schreiben. Es gibt keine offizielle Regelung, falsch ist keine Schreibweise, aber aus oben genannten Gründen würde ich dazu raten, es wie folgt zu schreiben:

> Frontend

Ferne rate ich eine Liste von Angliszismen zu studieren, um ein Gefühl zu bekommen: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Anglizismen

Persönlicher Kommentar: Ich rate von Bindestrichen ab, sie sind ein spezielles Stilmittel, um die Einzelwörter besonders hervor zu heben. Von daher würde ich immer die Schreibung ohne bevorzugen.

Comment: @Thomas Zu deinem Kommentar. Ich verstehe, dass du die Schreibweise ohne Bindestrich bevorzugst. Geht mir manchmal genauso. Im Deutschen ist aber, wie du bereits andeutest, bei Wörtern  mit führendem Einzelbuchstaben (E-Mail, T-Shirt, U-Bahn) der Bindestrich Pflicht. Da gibt es (noch) keinen Graubereich. Persönliche Empfehlungen die vom Standard abweichen können für Nichtmuttersprachler verwirrend sein [vgl. Eintrag bei duden.de für E-Mail](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/E_Mail)

Comment: @mtwde Ich habe es schweren Herzens rausgenommen, um hier niemanden zu verwirren, danke für den Hinweis.

Answer (score 3):

Im englischen ist ein Frontend das "Gegenteil" vom Backend. Ich hab ehrlich gesagt noch nie (weder im Englischen noch im Deutschen) die Schreibweise "Back-End" gesehen, sondern immer nur "Backend". Dementsprechend würde ich analog dazu die "Frontend"-Schreibweise bevorzugen.

Comment: also ich kenne aus dem Englischen sowohl "backend" als auch "back-end" oder "back end", denke nicht, dass man diese Frage abschließend klären kann...

Comment: Für die Frage ist es an sich vollkommen irrelevant, wie man das auf Englisch schreibt.

Answer (score 0):

Anders als die meisten Beiträger hier würde ich das Augenmerk weniger auf formale Regeln der Orthographie im Deutschen richten (wo auch immer diese notiert und von wem auch immer sie erdacht wurden). Die Regeln sind auch nur ein Versuch, Tradition und gute Praxis - nämlich zur Förderung der Lesbarkeit und Regelmäßigkeit - in abstrakter Form festzuhalten.

Überdies führen die Regeln ja, wie man bei den Antworten zu dieser Frage sieht, dann eben doch nicht zu einer eindeutigen Antwort, wie so ein Wort zu scheiben ist.

Also kuckt man sich lieber an, welche Anforderungen man hat, und entscheidet dann für jene Variante, die die Anforderungen in Summe am besten erfüllt.

Die Haupt-Anforderungen, die ich hätte, wäre:

- Die Schreibung soll das *Erkennen auf einen Blick* erleichtern.

Wir lesen ja nicht Buchstabe für Buchstabe, sondern wir erkennen Wörter wie wir Gesichter erkennen: an ihrem Gesamtbild. (Das gilt nicht nur für Wörter, das kann für ganze Phrasen gelten).

Leider führt diese Anforderung nicht automatisch zur Entscheidung für eine bestimmte Schreibung. Erkennen beruht ja auf Wiederholung. Die Frage des Erkennens hängt also damit zusammen, welche Schreibung möglicherweise sowieso schon etabliert ist.

Ergänzend werden noch folgende Kriterien eine Rolle spielen:

- Das Wort soll sich ins Schriftbild des Deutschen fügen
- Die Schreibung soll flüssiges Lesen ermöglichen
- Die Schreibung soll nicht dazu einladen, sich in einer falschen Lesung zu verrennen
- Bindestrich-Schreibungen nur dort, wo der Bindestrich das Lesen erleichtert statt es zu behindern
- Schreibungen nur mit Leerzeichen ("Deppenleerzeichen") sind ausgeschlossen. In solchen Fällen verwendet man im Deutschen den Bindestrich.
- Je häufiger ein Wort verwendet wird, desto weniger wird man es mit Bindestrich schreiben (da der Bindestrich eine Lesehilfe sein soll, und bei häufiger Wortverwendung kann man davon ausgehen, dass des Lesers Auge sich an das Wort gewöhnt hat und der Hilfe nicht bedarf).

Comment: Zu deinem zweiten Absatz: Ich denke "Wie du willst, solange du weißt, warum" **ist** eine eindeutige Antwort, die die Regeln geben. Und du schreibst hier schon wieder arrogant vom "Deppenleerzeichen", obwohl das im konkreten Fall sogar ausdrücklich erlaubt ist.

Comment: @tofro  Man mag argumentieren, dass *Front End* eine mögliche Schreibung im Deutschen ist, weil es im Englischen eine zulässige Schreibung ist und man ja Wörter auch unverändert aus dem Englischen übernehmen können sollte. Aber moment mal. Im Englischen hieße es natürlich nicht *Front End* sondern *front end*. Ich hätte nichts dagegen, dies so (und kursiv) in einem ansonsten deutschen Text zu finden. Jedoch die Enzelwörter wie deutsche Substantive groß zu schreiben und dann aber das dem Deutschen uneigentümliche Toleranzapostelleerzeichen drin zu lassen, ist inkonsequent und damit unschön.

Comment: Nein. Lies doch einfach die von dir so verabscheuten Regeln. Da steht's drin, dass man das exakt so schreiben darf.

Answer (score -1):

Die deutschen Rechtschreibregeln unterscheiden bei Zusammensetzungen von aus fremden Sprachen übernommenen Begriffen, ob ein Substantiv(S), Adjektiv/Adverb(A), Verb (V) oder was anderes (M) zusammengesetzt wird.

Unter der Annahme, das *Front* und *Back* hier substantivisch gebraucht werden, gilt:

Für Zusammensetzungen der Form (S) + (S) sind nur Zusammenschreibung und Schreibung mit Bindestrich zugelassen (§37 und 45), also

> Frontend, Backend
>
> Front-End, Back-End

Nimmt man an, dass *Front* und *Back* hier *Adjektive* wären, was durchaus sein kann, gelten für (A) + (S) leicht andere Regeln, man dürfte nämlich wahlweise auseinander und zusammen schreiben, sofern "der Hauptakzent auf dem ersten Bestandteil liegt", was hier der Fall ist (§37E4):

> Frontend, Backend
>
> Front End, Back End

Bindestrichschreibung ist für diesen Fall nicht vorgesehen.

An sich gibt es also für alle möglichen Schreibungem (zusammen, auseinander, mit Bindestrich) eine fundierte Rechtfertigung. Was nicht möglich ist, ist, einen Wortbestandteil wie im Englischen klein zu schreiben.

Die Form "Backend" würde ich lieber nicht nehmen, weil eine Verwechslung mit dem deutschen Partizip "backend" möglich ist.

Meine persönliche Praxis: Ich schreibe nach §37E4 auseinander.

Comment: Die Verwechslung zur "backend" sehe ich nicht, weil ich - abgesehen vom Satzanfang - keine Situation kenne, in der das Wort groß zu schreiben wäre und umgekehrt das eingangs gefragte Wort im Deutschen auf gar keinen Fall klein schreiben könnte. Trotzdem hilfreich und plausibel, vielen Dank.

Comment: @romeoyankee "schlüssig und dauerhaft verwechseln" wird man das wohl eher nicht, das stimmt schon. Aber ich finde, das Auge bleibt hier beim Lesen kurz irritiert hängen (meins zumindestens)

Comment: Auch der inhaltliche Kontext dürfte kaum eine Verwechslung zulassen sowie der Satzbau nicht. Außerdem geht es um Frontend, und eine Symmetrieregel gibt es auch nicht.